# Options for combining multiple Amazon Lex bots

Tags: amazon-lex

I work in a large enterprise where multiple teams are developing Lex bots (on separate accounts).  Each bot supports a different domain or application,. In some cases, it would be nice for a single user interface to ask a question without needing to know which bot to ask. Is there a way to federate bots, or to forward un-recognized intentions to 'backup' bots?

I feel like what I really want to do is treat each bot as a skill is treated in Alexa, except I'm in the position (through entitlements) to know which 'skills' would be appropriate for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is that you would need to develop a custom application that delivers a user's input to each of your company's array of bots.

You'd need to look at the NLU Confidence score from each Bot's response to decide which  response is the most accurate to return to the user. Would also be worthwhile keeping some state in your app to remember which Bot the user is currently interacting with and defaulting to that Bot for successive user inputs. Should you reach a point where the confidence score is low, it might present a signal to you to test the user's input across the other Bots.

What you'll need to be aware of here is that your costs will increase with each additional Bot that you add. So, assuming you have 5 area-specific Bots, one inbound message from your user could result in 5 Lex calls. As you start moving into significant volumes of interactions, this could start proving to be an obstacle.

An alternative would be to use a custom fallback intent to invoke a Lambda function that calls your Bot orchestration function. Assuming that you're able to find the correct Bot to handle the user's query, you'd need to remember that so succesive messages now get routed to that Bot.